# Using cpp-netlib 0.8 as a HTTP Proxy - Helpless

Tags: c++, http, networking

I am trying to use cpp-netlib in a project of mine. I simply need to create a HTTP proxy into which I can plug in some functionality later. For now, I just need to listen to requests, send request to a new site, and forward the answer of the new request to the first request.

This is the code I have so far:

```
std::string ip = source(request);
http::client client;
std::ostringstream url;
url << "www.example.com/image.jpg";
http::client::request clientRequest(url.str());
http::client::response clientResponse = client.get(clientRequest);
response = server::response::stock_reply(server::response::ok);
response.headers = clientResponse.headers(); //This is not possible - not correct type or something
response.content = clientResponse.body();
```

Results in `error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::multimap<_Kty,_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

A request to the test image I am using yields 19.4kb data in the response. If I do the same request through the above code (without header copying) I get an answer with about 4kb data, which the browser tries to show as text (default header). It does seem like an image though, even in text.

Anyone out there that is familiar with cpp-netlib-0.8? is `response.content = clientResponse.body();` the correct way? How can I add the correct headers?

It's altogether too much template weirdness in cpp-netlib for me to understand it right now!

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
response.content = clientResponse.body();
```

the correct way is:

```
std::string body_content = body(clientResponse);
```

also, you are using `response` as variable, while your variable is actually `clientResponse`

For more examples read [cpp-netlib v0.8 documentation](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/)